# Are these known limitations.bugs of the Outlook AutoFormatRules object model?

Tags: vba, filter, outlook, autoformat

This is a sequel to [Why does Outlook VBA AutoFormatRules.Add not add an AutoFormatRule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421846/why-does-outlook-vba-autoformatrules-add-not-add-an-autoformatrule/76422084#76422084).

Autoformat rules in Outlook can't be exported/imported/otherwise transferred to a different Outlook profile. I'm trying to work around that limitation by programmatically reading the rules, writing them to XML, and reading the XML in a different Outlook profile.

I'm hitting two limitations, and I wonder if these are known/by design. If so, I can give up on this project altogether.

1. I'm working with autoformat rules that apply a color to appointments based on words in their subject line. When I create an AutoFormatRule programmatically, I only have access to the Font object of the rule. Nothing related to appointment color seems to be available in the AutoFormatRules object model. Is that right?
2. When I recreate the AutoFormatRule through VBA, and set the Filter property to the saved filter from the XML, the rule shows up in the UI, but the filter doesn't. I'm taking the filter exactly as I read it from the existing rule, escaping quotes as needed.

So are both of these known limitations, did Microsoft not bother to implement?

Comment: It is not clear what code is used for getting these tasks done in Outlook. And I'd suggest focusing on a single issue when posting here.

Comment: Hi @EugeneAstafiev, in my view I'm focusing on a single issue: known limitations of the AutoFormatRules object model. I'm describing what I'm trying to do for context, I'm not asking to review or debug my code. Which is also why I didn't post my code: my exact code is beside the point.

Comment: Are you able to that manually in Outlook? If so, have you checked object configurations after? What is missed in your code in that case?

Comment: Yes, I can configure a rule in Outlook to apply color to appointments based on words in the subject. The result is that in the object model, the rule is there, the filter is configured and recognizable, but the color is just not there at all. There seems  to be no corresponding property.

Comment: Which makes it an apparent limitation of the OM, which I'm trying to verify.

Answer (score 0):

If by "appointment color" you mean the appointment category, you can access it through `AppointmentItem.Categories`.

Comment: Nope, I don;t mean category, I mean the color you can apply through an AutoFormatRule. This is separate from categories.

Comment: Also, accessing the category of the appointment through the AppoitmentItem object model is no doubt possible, but doesn't relate to AutoFormatRules, the topic under discussion.